# asp.net user control - upload image control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

i want to create a user control that will display an image (the location of the image is store in my db) the control will have the ability to change the image or delete it.

i want to build another control that will hold some of that control.

what are the properties that i need to set or get from the first control to the second and then to the page that will hold them?

Answer (score 1):

well, it seems that we are talking about inheritance,

in my first thinking to solve this quickly you have to create a class (maybe on app_code dir) that inherits from usercontrol. Here you gonna implements tha base methods that will be used for each derived classes.

when you have this "Base class" implemented your control will not inherits fom the default usercontrol, but will from your base class.

by this way you can create a kind of base class that provides adicional properies or methods for your purposes (thats a kind of extension if you dont understand much of oop)